# Sorteo | Como hacer una animacion de varios numeros de telefono y que salga uno al azar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema que no estoy resolviendo...
Se trata que debo hacer una pagina en la que debo recorrer varios numeros de telefonos que estan en un json, array o en una base de datos, y al darle el boton sortear, empiece una animacion de los numeros todos pasando asi rapido como se ve aveces en la television, con javascript o algun otro lenguaje, y cuando le de a parar, me salga un numero de ese array...
No se si hay alguna libreria para lograr ese efecti y luego un algoritmo para recorrer tengo solo por el momento uno muy basico como este:

html:

```
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" name="btnsorteo" id="btnsorteo">
                            Parar
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

Y el js es asi:

```
var boton=document.getElementById("btnsorteo");

boton.onclick=function sorteo () {

    participantes=["  0982820405    Verónica", "0972810576  Vicente", "982211370    Saida", "0971650876     Liliana",
  "0971112309   Carlos Andrés","0961438607  Paulina","0971226914    Elias","0981113964  Cesar","0976549865  Manuel"];



    var numero_participantes=participantes.length;
    numero=Math.floor(Math.random()*numero_participantes);
    //numero=Math.floor(Math.random()*numero_participantes2);
    alert('El ganador es:'+participantes[numero]);

}
```

Pero como ven, solo recorre los que estan en ese array, y no hace ningun efecto animado, no se si con jquery o algo se puede lograr tambien eso, si conocen algun dato aunque sea cualquier cosa les agradecere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a [Mathew](https://github.com/matthewlein/jQuery-jSlots) que desarrollo una libreria Slots.js se puede adaptar para hacer lo que buscas, aqui el codigo, solo agrega los elementos de tu lista:

```js
$(function() {

    var msa = [

            { name: "0982820405    Verónica" },
            { name:"0972810576  Vicente" },
            { name: "982211370    Saida" },
            { name:"0971650876     Liliana" },
            { name: "0971112309   Carlos Andrés" },
            { name: "0971226914    Elias" },
            { name: "9823423423 Pancho" },
            { name: "465477987   Juanita" },
            { name: "654654654   Brandon" },
        
        ],
        $input = $('input'),
        random_index;

    //lista recursiva hasta detenerse en el elemento configurado
    function makeSlotList(list){
        //soporta hasta 18 valores en la animacion
        if(list.length<20){//el valor puede ser ajustado
            var index = _.random(msa.length-1);
            if(list.length===1){
                /*
                    elemento inicial de la lista
                */
                random_index = index;
            }
            list.push( '<li index='+_.random(msa.length-1)+'>'+msa[index].name+'</li>' );
            return makeSlotList(list);
        } else {
            //dio un giro
            //la entrada se limpia
            $input.val('');
            // se agrega el elemento seleccionado
            $('#slot').html(list.join('')).parent().show().trigger('spin');
            return list;
        }
    }

    //se crea la lista de elementos o slot
    function makeSlots(){
        //inicia en el valor aleatorio previo
        var list = ['<li>'+$input.val()+'</li>'];

        //se hace recursivo el llamado
        makeSlotList(list);
    }

    $('#slot').jSlots({
        number: 1,
        spinner : '.jSlots-wrapper',
        spinEvent: 'spin',
        time: 300,
        loops: 1,
        endNum: 2,//finaliza en el segundo elmento del arreglo aleatorio
        onEnd: function(finalElement){
            //set result
            $input.val(msa[random_index].name);
            //oculta spiner
            $(this.spinner).hide();
        }
    });

    //elemento aleatorio
    $('#random_location').on('click', makeSlots);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://bl.ocks.org/sarahjsquire/raw/4706c4d48962e9962175/6ad2d061715fbc9f6de328ecb5ab5d3a6c1003d5/jquery.jSlots.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="https://bl.ocks.org/sarahjsquire/raw/4706c4d48962e9962175/6ad2d061715fbc9f6de328ecb5ab5d3a6c1003d5/jquery.jSlots.js"></script>


<style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    li, ul { padding: 0; margin:0; }
    input {
        margin: 4px 0;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 5px 4px 4px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 350px;
    }
    #slot li {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 6px 4px 6px 6px;
        line-height: normal;
        height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #slot_wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    .jSlots-wrapper {
        margin: 4px 0;
        overflow: hidden; /*oculta la lista */
        height: 29px; /*altura de caca slot */
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        display: none;
    }
    #slot {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div id="slot_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="search">
    <ul id="slot">
        <!-- la lista llenada por cada elemento -->
        <li>test</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li><li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" id="random_location">Gira la ruleta</button>
```

saludos

Comment: Me ayudaste bastante, no habia encontrado esa libreria, pero muchas gracias por el aporte!

Comment: Y tengo una pregunta mas, tu crees que puede ser posible que esos valores que me saque pueda recorrer siendo un json?, pero me imagino que habria que hacer algo parecido a un JSON.parse() para convertir el json a un array cierto?

Comment: Pues dependiendo de como venga tu json en dado caso revisa  let jsonObject = response.data;  y haces un map.