# Sorteo | Estoy intentando hacer una herramienta de "sorteo", donde el resultado es un resultado predefinido

Tags: javascript

Buen día, estoy intentando hacer una **herramienta de sorteo**, en la cual, permita ingresar nombres a una lista vacía, en el código hice que siempre me muestre específicamente un resultado si ese nombre se agrega a la lista. Puedo mostrarlo tanto en consola, como en el body del documento **(Estoy utilizando JavaScript**). Solo me falta hacer la animación, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerla, no es un trabajo, ni una tarea, es solo un ejercicio de chill, para divertirse. Adjunto acá el código en JS, y así poder recibir alguna recomendación con respecto a como poder hacer esa simulación de animación para la herramienta de **“sorteo random”**

```
let contador = 0;
const nombres = [];
let rifa;
do {    
    rifa= prompt(`Ingrese los nombres, presione '1' para parar, lleva ${contador} nombres: `);
    nombres.push(rifa);

    if (!isNaN(rifa)){
        nombres.pop(rifa);
        nombres.push(rifa);
    }    
    contador ++
    if (contador > 10){
        alert (`Ya introdujo ${contador} nombres`);
        break
    }           
} while (rifa !=1);
nombres.pop(rifa);

const found = nombres.find(element => element == "manuel");

console.log(`El array tiene los nombres : ${nombres}`);
console.log(`El ganador de la rifa es: ${found}`)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! de que animacion hablas???

Comment: Vale, juraba que ya tenia medallas y todo, creo que abrio con otro correo, en fin, asi como formulo alguien en esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/250965/306841 , la respuesta que le planteo alguien, este agrego un codigo ejecutable en el cual esta una animacion de girar ruleta la que elige uno de los numeros aleatorios dentro de su objeto, lo que yo quiero es, que dentro de mi array que va aumentando segun el numero de personas agregagas, haga una animacion simple similar y siempre caiga la misma persona, asi como hice con el  metodo find();, que simule la animacion

Comment: ¿y porque no copias ese código y lo adaptas a lo tuyo directamente?  Veo que usa librerias externas que desconozco que seguramente hacen ese efecto que buscas.

Comment: si, eso es lo que vi que agrego varias librerias, bueno, probare a agregarlas igual e ir moviendole a las funciones que hizo, lo que no entiendo es por que encerro todo dentro de una funcion, imagino que son cosas de jquery, estoy comenzando con js apenas y ando haciendo proyectitos para familiarizarme y trolear a los compañeros de clase, jaja

Comment: Si estás empezando con javascript te recomiendo que use https://jsfiddle.net para la depuración de tu código (a mi me sirve mucho para dar respuestas rápidas). Es decir, yo cogeria ese código de ese enlace que has puesto, lo pegaria en su sitio en jsfiddle, y luego lo ejecutaria. Si funciona entonces ya puedes modificarlo y adaptarlo a lo tuyo ahi mismo de forma ágil. Suerte!

Comment: Oh, gracias, gracias, yo estoy utilizando el VS con node para ejecutar y eso, pero si, esta utilizando jquery, ahi si no tengo la menor idea, voy a seguir buscando formas de poder hacerlo, seguro ha de haber una forma mas simple, gracias por la recomendacion!